# Initialize a class registered in a DI container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I've a service which starts a timer is its constructor to perform some periodic checks

```
internal class PeriodicCheckService : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Timer _checkTimer;

    public PeriodicCheckService (IService1 service, PeriodicOptions options)
    {
        _checkTimer = new Timer(timerCallback, null, 0, options.Period);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to register this service in a Dependency Injection container so I've implemented this extension method:

```
public static IServiceCollection EnablePeriodicCheck(this IServiceCollection services, Action<PeriodicOptions> options)
{
    services.Configure(options);
    services.TryAddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
    {
        var options = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<PeriodicOptions>();
        var service1= serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService1>();
        
        return new PeriodicCheckService (service1, options);
    });

    return services;
}
```

I've a console application implemented in .net c# where I register all the needed service and of course there is also this registration

```
services.EnablePeriodicCheck(options =>
{
    options.Period = Settings.Days;
});
```

where Settings is an internal class depending in turn on a different registered service.

Now, come to the question: the timer is not started, because the factory is never called since no service uses that specific PeriodicCheck component. That is a standalone service and I want just to execute its constructor when the container is built.

A way to achieve what I want could be using this workaraound

- Make the service public
- Where I register the service doing something like `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(PeriodicCheckService));`

That way I force the container to create an single instance of the PeriodicCheckService class and so the timer could be initialized but I don't want to do that. I hope there is a clean way to achieve the same:) Thanks

Ps. The project type is just a console application, not an Asp.net core.

Comment: Triggering this scheduled operation merely by building the container or resolving its instance is very implicit and will certainly cause confusion with other developers that might be working now (or in the future) on your project. I'd suggest adding a very explicit `Start()` method on `PeriodicCheckService`. This way you can resolve it (as Chris already suggested) and call it's `Start` method.

Comment: Besides, seems to me you can reduce the registration to simply `services.AddSingleton<PeriodicCheckService>();`

Answer (score 0):

What is not clean about:

```
this.checkService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(PeriodicCheckService));
```

- You need to store the reference to the instance somewhere to ensure it doesn't get prematurely cleaned up.

In DI cases we don't want instances until the logic needs them, DI only instantiates and provides instances when they are required, executing the above magic code without letting you see it.

If you have no logical DI container to force the instance to be created then `GetRequiredService()` is the appropriate way to resolve the injected instance on demand.

Anything else you do in this space is likely to look less *clean* and hide the logic in a way that you don't notice it, which is just more technical debt you don't need.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Because I want to keep the business class internal to the assembly where the service component is defined. For the life cycle of the object, I'm fine if that is managed by the container. When the container is unresolved, the service is disposed and the timer is stopped.
Practically I want to achieve the same when you do something services.AddHealthChecks(); you don't need to call container.GetRequiredService<IHealthChecks>().StartCheck(); everything is done underneath by the method so to me all the details are hidden.

Comment: For the HealthChecks, for example, I think it just register a HostedService that does the job but here I've not an app to build so I fear I cannot use the same mechanism

Comment: All this does is obfuscate the timer and the check logic. This really should be promoted out or don't both using DI at all. Either fnd a suitable container that this can be a dependency for or deliberately instantiate the logic. You can still make use of a factory pattern to encapsulate the instatiation logic, if DI doesn't work for you, you don't need to use it.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller "You need to store the reference to the instance somewhere to ensure it doesn't get prematurely cleaned up." That's not the case when the service is singleton or implements `IDisposable` (and both conditions are met). In that case the `ServiceProvider` will keep a reference to the class. Besides, the (running) `Timer` will also cause the `PeriodicCheckService` to stay rooted.

Comment: @user2896152 "Practically I want to achieve the same when you do something services.AddHealthChecks();". This is not how health checks works. It registers an `IHostedService`. The hosted service will -after the container is constructed- get resolved and started. So the framework is actively calling `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` on hosted services. But since you are running a console application, there is no framework and the best thing here is to call "StartAsync" on your `PeriodicCheckService` manually.